# RoR: Minitest error: Expected false to be truthy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

looking for help implementing a simple first test using minitest (Rails 5, Ruby 2.7.0)

car_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CarTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'valid car' do
    car = Car.new(title: 'SALOON', style: '1')
    assert car.valid?
  end

end
```

My model car.rb

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, :style, presence: true
end
```

When I run test: rake test TEST=test/models/car_test.rb

```
Expected false to be truthy.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert thing.valid?` is a testing anti-pattern that was popularized by the Rails Tutorial book. Its an anti-pattern since you're testing every single validation at once and the possibilities for both false positives and negatives are huge. The error message also tells you absolutely nothing about why the test failed.

Instead if you want to test validations use the [errors object](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

```
require 'test_helper'

class CarTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'title must be present' do
    car = Car.new(title: '')
    car.valid?
    assert_includes car.errors.messages[:title], "can't be blank"
  end
  test 'style must be present' do
    car = Car.new(style: '')
    car.valid?
    assert_includes car.errors.messages[:style], "can't be blank"
  end
end
```

Comment: [Shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) makes writing these tests a lot less arduous.